# Simplify Building Dictionaries

Tags: c#, dictionary, refactoring

I'm trying to send a Dictionary as a parameter to a method. It works, but it's getting a bit tedious. I'm doing it a million times and I'd like to do it a little slicker if at all possible. Right now, this is how it looks:

```
MyMethod(new Dictionary<string, object> { { string1, value1 }, { string2, value2 } });
```

I'd like to get it to look more like this:

```
MyMethod({ string1, value1 }, { string2, value2 });
```

Is this a pipe dream? Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: I would think not possible, but I don't know

Comment: Just split it up onto more than one line, or add new lines

Comment: Why are you creating a million dictionaries in the first place?  Are you unit testing?

Comment: A JavaScript programmer wondering C# could be more like it?

Comment: Good thought process, @ErickPetru, but nope. I'm a .Net guy. Very much getting into the front-end, though. Trying to be a two-way guy in that manner. On a VERY front-end heavy project right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there's any way to get the type of syntax you're looking for.  The closest, and shortest thing I can think of would be to define something like:

```
using D = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object>;
```

And then you could do:

```
MyMethod(new D {{string1, value1},{string2, value2}});
```

Which is a bit shorter, but probably still not ideal.

Comment: That's kinda being mean to members of your team though.  Give it at least a 1 word name, rather than a 1 letter name.

Comment: @Servy, yeah pretty mean.  I was just going for maximum brevity.

Comment: All good answers, but I'll "accept" this one. I did modify it to make it a class that extends Dictionary<string, object> instead, however, and I called it "Params," as that's what it is.

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty much a pipe dream. You *could* create a generic `DictionaryBuilder` class, with a non-generic class containing a generic `DictionaryBuilder.Start` method, so you could write:

```
MyMethod(DictionaryBuilder.Start(string1, value1).Add(string2, value2).Build());
```

... but that's not exactly nice either.

To use a collection initializer for a new object (rather than an embedded initializer), you *have* to call the constructor, which means specifying the type arguments.

Comment: This was one of my thoughts. I wonder if it can be made a bit tighter, though?

Comment: @vbullinger: I don't think so, without hacks like Eric's which aren't really nice.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way I know of to do exactly what you're looking for, but you can cheat a little, and use a variable argument list.  You lose some type-checking, and you'll get an exception if you don't call it exactly right, but it is less wordy:

```
void MyMethod( params object[] arr ) {
    var d = new Dictionary<string,object>();
    for( int i=0; i<arr.Length; i+=2 ) {
        d.Add( (string)arr[i], arr[i+1] );
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
MyMethod( string1, value1, string2, value2 );
```

Comment: that might open a can of worms though

Comment: I also had this idea, and I also had AD.Net's idea :)  I wonder if this could be made slightly better somehow?

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on shortening your method inputs to the extreme, I was thinking along the same lines as Ethan Brown. Here's a little program that uses `params` for inputting your dictionary elements.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyMethod("Key1", 1, "Key2", 2, "Key3", 3);
    }

    static void MyMethod(params object[] alternatingKeysValues)
    {
        var dictionary = AlternatingKeysValuesToDictionary(alternatingKeysValues);
        // etc...
    }

    static Dictionary<string, object> AlternatingKeysValuesToDictionary(params object[] alternatingKeysValues)
    {
        if (alternatingKeysValues.Count() % 2 == 1)
            throw new ArgumentException("AlternatingKeysValues must contain an even number of items.");
        return Enumerable
            .Range(1, alternatingKeysValues.Count() / 2)
            .ToDictionary(
                i => (string)alternatingKeysValues.ElementAt(i * 2 - 2),
                i => alternatingKeysValues.ElementAt(i));
    }
}
```

That said, I think something like Eric's answer is actually better. Assigning a short-cut to the very wordy `Dictionary<object, string>` gets you pretty close to your ideal without sacrificing clarity or the natural error checking provided by `Dictionary`'s built-in collection initializer.

I would go for a slightly more clear wording, however:

```
using Dict = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object>;
```

Usage:

```
MyMethod(new Dict {{string1, value1},{string2, value2}});
```

Better yet, replace `Dict` with something that actually describes what your dictionary contains, e.g., fruitPrices if your key is `FruitName` and your value is `Price`.

Comment: I highly obfuscated my code (I REALLY wonder why a lot of people don't when they post questions here). I'm sending pairs of column name/values to build queries. So the class could be "Parameters," or "Params," maybe? Basically, it's a huge refactor that builds queries based on this dictionary, adding " && [tablename].[key] = [value]" for each item in the dictionary. Since it's entity framework, I'm using the entity name as the table name, pluralized. And I'm doing this a million times, so it's nice to get the shorthand.

Comment: I one-upped this: I made a Params class that extended Dictionary<string, object>. Then it's easier to include this everywhere. It's in a namespace most of these files are already using anyway.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, I would recommend `NamedValues = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object>;`. I think `NamedValues` clearly conveys that each pair contains a column name and a value.